# Doubt in proof of theorem 8.20 of Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am self studying number theory from Tom M Apostol Dirichlet Series and Modular functions in number theory and I have a doubt in theorem 8.20 of the book. 
I am attaching images of relevant results.

> The Theorem-- [image]

[image]

> My doubt is in last  paragraph  of proof how by integral analog of Landau theorem function on left is analytic in half plane $\sigma$ > 1/2 .

Landau theorem -
[image]

What I could deduce using Landau theorem--> The function on right is analytic. So, the function on left converges for $ \sigma$ >1 , which is not similar to result deduced by Apostol.

Can somebody please help to make deduction given in the book .

Comment: Do you know Landau's Theorem?

Comment: @Conrad it's statement is given in question . Is Landau theorem something else?

Comment: Landau's theorem is the statement that a Dirichlet series/integral with coefficients (integrating function) of constant sign must have a singularity at the real value on the abscissa of convergence; it is usually used in the counterpositive (no singularity at a real value and constant sign coefficients implies abscissa is strictly to the left) or to show omega results (we know the abscisssa and no singularity, hence coefficients/integrating function must change sign indefinitely, hence something cannot be always greater than something else, but they must switch order indefinitely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first part is to assume that  for some $\Re(s) > 1$, $L_n(s)=\sum_{n\le x}\lambda(n)n^{-s}= 0$, then take a sequence $t_k$ such that for $p\le x$, $p^{-s-it_k}\to  -p^{-s}$ which implies that $n^{-s-it_k}\to\lambda(n)n^{-s}$ and hence $\zeta_n(z+s+it_k)\to L_n(z+s)$ uniformly around $z=0$ which means that for $k$ large enough $\zeta_n(s+it_k+z)$ has a zero near $z=0$.
- The last part is that $\forall x > X,\sum_{n\le x} \lambda(n)n^{-1}\ge 0$ implies $F(s)=\int_X^\infty (\sum_{n\le x}\lambda(n)n^{-1})x^{-s}dx$ has a singularity at its abscissa of convergence $\sigma$.

  Proof : if $F$ is analytic then $F(\sigma-\epsilon) = \sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{\epsilon^k}{k!} \int_X^\infty (\sum_{n\le x}\lambda(n)n^{-1})x^{-\sigma} (\log x)^k dx$ if it is finite then we can invert $\sum,\int$ obtaining that $\int_X^\infty (\sum_{n\le x}\lambda(n)n^{-1})x^{-\sigma+\epsilon}dx$ is finite.

  The analyticity of the LHS shows $\sigma=1/2$.

I don't know about the converse, assuming the RH what can we say about the zeros of $\zeta_n$ and the sign of $\sum_{n\le x}\lambda(n)n^{-1}$ ?

Comment: my doubt was how to deduce that function on left is analytic everywhere in half plane $\sigma$ >1/2 using integral analog of Landau 's theorem  . But you are perhaps explaining something else.

Comment: The $\ge 0$ condition implies the RHS has a singularity on the real axis at its abscissa of convergence $\sigma$. The LHS is analytic on $(1/2,\infty)$ thus it must be $\sigma=1/2$. Once the RHS converges for $\Re(s) > 1/2$ then the LHS is analytic for $\Re(s) > 1/2$ (ie. the RH is true).

Comment: I understand why LHS is analytic on (1/2, $\infty $) . But why condition that C(x) is nonnegative implies that RHS has a singularity on real axis at its abcisaa of convergence?

Comment: Also , which result you are using to reduce that if RHS converges for $\sigma$ >1/2 , then LHS is analytic for $\sigma$>1/2 ?

Comment: Expand $F(\sigma-\epsilon)$ in a Taylor series in $\epsilon$, every term is non-negative and their formal sum is $\int_{n_0}^\infty C(x)x^{-\sigma+\epsilon}dx$ which has to be finite

Comment: It is obvious that the RHS is complex differentiable, holomorphic, analytic on its half-plane of convergence. The equality between LHS and RHS is true everywhere both sides are analytic (this is called analytic continuation)

Comment: thanks a lot for such a great explanation.